# Angularjs directive doesn't get data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have service which gets data from server and sends it to controller:

Service:

```
publicApp.angularModule.factory('resultService', function ($http) {
        return {
            getResult: function() {
                return $http.get("/Result/GetResult")
                    .success(function(result) {
                        return result.data;
                    }).error(function(result) {
                        console.log("error" + result);
                    });
            },
        };
    });
```

Controller:

```
publicApp.angularModule.controller('PublicResultCtrl', function ($scope, $location, resultService) {

    resultService.getResult().then(function (resultResponse) {
        $scope.data = resultResponse.data;
        $scope.graph = [];

        _.forEach($scope.data.TreningExerciseScores, function(item) {
            $scope.graph.push(addDataToGraph(item.Item2, item.Item1));
        });

    });

    var addDataToGraph = function (num, text) {
        return {
            y: num,
            legendText: text,
        };
    };

});
```

And I have directive which should get data from controller. I call directive like this:

```
<div id="graph" style="width: 200px; height: 200px" canvasjs graphData="graph"></div>
```

And here is my directive:

```
publicApp.angularModule.directive('canvasjs', function () {


    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {data : '=graphData'} ,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch('data', function (data) {
                    console.log(scope.data);

            });         
        }
    };
});
```

But scope.data is undefined. I know that $http.get is async operation but shouldn't scope.$watch get updates ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass value to directive as: `canvasjs="graph"`.

In my example I simulate response from service and return promise.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="fessCntrl">
    <div id="graph" style="width: 200px; height: 200px" canvasjs="graph"></div>
    <pre>   graph:  {{graph|json}}  </pre>
    <pre>   data:  {{data|json}}  </pre>  
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var fessmodule = angular.module('myModule', ['ngResource']);

fessmodule.controller('fessCntrl', function ($scope, resultService) {

    resultService.getResult().then(function (resultResponse) {
        console.log(resultResponse);

        $scope.data = resultResponse.data;
        $scope.graph = [];

        angular.forEach($scope.data.TreningExerciseScores, function (item, key) {
            $scope.graph.push(addDataToGraph(item.Item2, item.Item1));
        });


    });

    var addDataToGraph = function (num, text) {
        return {
            y: num,
            legendText: text,
        };
    };

});

fessmodule.$inject = ['$scope', 'Data'];

fessmodule.directive('canvasjs', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch('data', function (data) {
                console.log("fff", scope.data);

            });
        }
    };
});

fessmodule.factory('resultService', ['$resource', '$q', function ($resource, $q) {
    var input = {
        data: {
            TreningExerciseScores: [{
                Item1: "aaa"
            },
            {
                Item2: "bbb"
            }]
        }
    };

    var factory = {
        getResult: function (selectedSubject) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            deferred.resolve(input);

            return deferred.promise;
        }

    }
    return factory;
}]);
```

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/639/)</kbd>

Comment: @hyperN see my answer and Demo.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to handle the promise in your controller:

```
resultService.getResult().then(function (resultResponse) {
        $scope.data = resultResponse.data;
        $scope.graph = [];

        _.forEach($scope.data.TreningExerciseScores, function(item) {
            $scope.graph.push(addDataToGraph(item.Item2, item.Item1));
        });

    });
```

There is no need to handle it in your service:

```
getResult: function() {
                return $http.get("/Result/GetResult");
            },
```

If you want to handle only the error in the service then you need to wrap in a promise again.  You can use `$q.when` for this:

```
getResult: function() {
                return $http.get("/Result/GetResult")
                    .success(function(result) {
                        return $q.when(result.data);
                    }).error(function(result) {
                        // not sure what you want to do here
                        console.log("error" + result);
                        return $q.when(result);

                    });
            },
```

`$q.when` will wrap a promise around the object if it is not already a promise.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've changed my code according to them, but still scope.data is undefined

Comment: Maybe you need to return `$q.when(result)` and not `result.data`. Otherwise, you are doing a `result.data.data`.

Comment: I've logged $scope.graph and everything was fine there so it's not problem with my service, I believe problem is in directive

Comment: Where are you logging?  Try logging result in your `resultService` and your controller.  See if you can see the `data` property on both.

Comment: You were right `result.data` in `resultService` was undefined, and  `result` was object, and in controller was everything ok

Comment: But in directive it's still undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can't return the data in a `success()` handler and expect it to make it back. You have to chain another promise (return `defer.promise()`), or do the `success` in your controller and modify the $scope in your result. Or just return the whole `$http` call which is already a promise.